# How to Generate Class Diagram from existing classes in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

I have created java entity classes inside a given package. I want to create a UML diagram for those java classes in the package. Any one know how to do it in NetBeans IDE 7? (I installed the plugin and it is working.)

Answer (score 2):

For those using Netbeans version 8, take a look at these plugins

easyUml -> http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55435/easyuml

PlantUml ->http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49069/plantuml

[Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/) is a software which also helps in generating UML diagrams.